# What does "basin" here mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> ‘Why, no. I didn’t know you were a chaplain.’ Yossarian stared at him with a big, fascinated grin. ‘I’ve never really seen a chaplain before.’ The chaplain flushed again and gazed down at his hands. He was a slight man of about thirty-two with tan hair and brown diffident eyes. His face was narrow and rather pale. An innocent nest of ancient pimple pricks lay in the **basin** of each cheek. Yossarian wanted to help him.
>
> —Catch 22

Found a [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/basin) may fit in

> A circular or oval valley or natural depression on the earth’s surface, especially one containing water:

Does it mean the hollow area(because chaplain was thin, so probably in the face too)at the centre of both cheeks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *basin* here is used to describe that the surface (of the face) is bit sunken, a bit depressed as you guessed it. The *previous sentence* in the paragraph supports what we think.

WordWebOnline has an entry for that which I think is close in meaning for this context

> [basin (#3)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/BASIN) - ***A natural depression*** in the surface of the land often with a lake at the bottom of it

Comment: The OED has a definition that might work: "A hollow depression, natural or artificial."

Comment: @snailplane Searched, could not get it.

Comment: @snailplane *OED 1* is available online; *Basin* is [here](http://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/690/mode/2up), where your definition is II. Links to the other volumes are [here on ELL](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/739/32).